# Jquery Not selector difficulty

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Edit: Ok just to get this straight, you use the not selector to filter attributes in a particular tag and not to filter child elements?

Can someone help me out whether I have some sort of syntax error here, or may be I'm not understanding the concept?

I have list items which when you click on, they change the font size of the body. Now the list item is within the body so its font changes to. I would like this UL to remain with the same font. so I am using the .not("#ulSize") as can be seen below. But this is not working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#liSmall").click(function () {
                $('body').not('#ulSize').removeClass('large normal').addClass('small');
            });
            $("#liNormal").click(function () {
                $('body').not('#ulSize').removeClass('large small').addClass('normal');
            });
            $("#liLarge").click(function () {
                $('body').not('#ulSize').removeClass('small normal').addClass('large');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .large
        {
            font-size: large;
        }

        .normal
        {
            font-size: medium;
        }

        .small
        {
            font-size: small;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ulSize">
        <li id="liSmall">Small Font</li>
        <li id="liNormal">Normal Font</li>
        <li id="liLarge">Large Font</li>
    </ul>
        Text in here!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you guys

Comment: `.not('#ulSize')` simply removes anything in the previous matching set that is `#ulSize`. And since `body` isn't `#ulSize` anyway... nothing happens. Also, `.not()` is not a selector. The selector is `:not()` with a colon.

Comment: so $('body:not("#ulSize")')... should do the trick? because I tried it too and I had no positive results!

Comment: You can't remove an element like that anyway you cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend refactoring your JS to something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#liSmall, #liNormal, #liLarge').on('click', function(e){
    $('body').removeClass('small medium large');
    switch(this.id){
      case 'liSmall': $('body').addClass('small'); break;
      case 'liMedium': $('body').addClass('medium'); break;
      case 'liLarge': $('body').addClass('large'); break;
    }
  });
});
```

And then hard-code a font-size on the `#ulSize` list, and let the browser do the rest.

```
#ulSize {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: OK, but this changes the font size on the LI that is clicked, not everything BUT the ul/li element, so it just seems backwards.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss You are very right, I misread what he was trying to do. I don't know why my answer got accepted, it was wrong :P I've fixed it now.

Comment: You have to add "normal" to the ul or it will inherit font size from the body as well.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I put in the comment about the CSS to cover that, but yes you could also add the normal class.

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $DefaultULSize = $('#ulSize').css('font-size');

        $("#liSmall").click(function () {
            $('body').removeClass('small normal large').addClass('small');
            $('#ulSize').css('font-size', $DefaultULSize);
        });
        $("#liNormal").click(function () {
            $('body').removeClass('small normal large').addClass('normal');
            $('#ulSize').css('font-size', $DefaultULSize);
        });
        $("#liLarge").click(function () {
            $('body').removeClass('small normal large').addClass('large');
            $('#ulSize').css('font-size', $DefaultULSize);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes this works perfect thank you, but to be honest I'm checking out some jquery tutorials and I would like to get the same results specifically using the not :)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `.not('#ulSize')` from your JavaScript and add `#ulSize { font-size: medium !important; }` to your CSS. Don't bloat your JS unnecessarily like others recommend doing, it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qwSt2/3/)

```
$('body').children().not('#ulSize').removeClass('large normal').addClass('small');
```

Answer (score 1):

selection.not(filter) returns the set of elements within the selection that match the filter.

What you are doing here is filtering the "body" tags which have no "ulSize" id, so your .not() filter is useless.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#liSmall").click(function () {
                $('body').removeClass('large normal').addClass('small');
            });
            $("#liNormal").click(function () {
                $('body').removeClass('large small').addClass('normal');
            });
            $("#liLarge").click(function () {
                $('body').removeClass('small normal').addClass('large');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .large
        {
            font-size: large;
        }

        .normal
        {
            font-size: medium;
        }

        .small
        {
            font-size: small;
        }
        #ulSize
        {
        font-size: 16px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ulSize">
        <li id="liSmall">Small Font</li>
        <li id="liNormal">Normal Font</li>
        <li id="liLarge">Large Font</li>
    </ul>
        Text in here!!!
</body>
</html>​
```

Working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cYa9q/

Comment: does not NOT change the LI font

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the fontsize of the page, why do you want to do that *per element*?

It's way easier to add/remove a class on the body-tag (or HTML-tag) and set up your CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one. Simpler Jquery coding and using NOT selector?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ulSize > li').click(function(event){
        $('body').children(':not(#ulSize > li)').removeClass('small normal large').addClass($(this).attr('id').substr(2).toLowerCase());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are doing a tutorial, so you want verbose jQuery, I get that.

You also want to do `.not()` syntax for the same reason.  I get that.

I embelished the example just so show with borders what is NOT getting changed.

SO, this does that:

```
var noto = $('#ulSize, #ulSize > li'); // stuff to NOT select/change
noto.css('border', 'solid lime 1px');// stuff that should not change
noto.addClass('normal');// avoid inheriting from the body.

var selecter = $('body').not(noto); // stuff TO change but NOT the noto stuff above.
selecter.css('border', 'solid red 1px');// border around stuff that should change.
// verbose click events for the demo
$("#liSmall").click(function() {
    selecter.removeClass('large normal').addClass('small');
});
$("#liNormal").click(function() {
    selecter.removeClass('large small').addClass('normal');
});
$("#liLarge").click(function() {
    selecter.removeClass('small normal').addClass('large');
});
```

For fun, give each li the class they are setting:

```
<body>
    <ul id="ulSize"> 
        <li id="liSmall" class='small'>Small Font</li> 
        <li id="liNormal" class='normal'>Normal Font</li> 
        <li id="liLarge" class='large' >Large Font</li> 
    </ul>
    <div id='myclass'>
    Text in here!!! 
    </div>
Text in the body
</body>
```

Then use it:

```
var noto = $('#ulSize, #ulSize > li');
var selecter = $('body').not(noto);
$('#liSmall, #liNormal, #liLarge').click(function(e) {
    selecter.removeClass('small normal large').addClass($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer! I learnt a lot from this!

Comment: Stupid me, css inheritance need: `noto.addClass('normal');`
  SO I added that.  Without this, the elements in the body inherit the css of the body.  This same issue applies to text in the ul element if you do not include that.